# read CSV file into pandas DataFrame, and build datetime index from multiple columns

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a CSV file like this:

```
2011    1   10  1000000
2011    1   11  998785
2011    1   12  1002940
2011    1   13  1004815
2011    1   14  1009415
2011    1   18  1011935
```

I want to read it into a DataFrame object and have a datetime typed index built from the frist 3 colomns.  The final DataFrame should look like this:

```
                     values
datetime(2011,1,10)  1000000
datetime(2011,1,11)  998785
...
```

How should I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

```
import io
import pandas as pd
content = io.BytesIO('''\
2011    1   10  1000000
2011    1   11  998785
2011    1   12  1002940
2011    1   13  1004815
2011    1   14  1009415
2011    1   18  1011935''')

df = pd.read_table(content, sep='\s+', parse_dates=[[0,1,2]], header=None)
df.columns=['date', 'values']
print(df)
```

yields

```
                 date   values
0 2011-01-10 00:00:00  1000000
1 2011-01-11 00:00:00   998785
2 2011-01-12 00:00:00  1002940
3 2011-01-13 00:00:00  1004815
4 2011-01-14 00:00:00  1009415
5 2011-01-18 00:00:00  1011935
```

Comment: Thanks. I got Error like :"Exception: Length mismatch (2 vs 4)". I am assuming the number of columns is incorrect. Is there a version mismatch with pandas?

Comment: Works perfectly for me with pandas 0.11.0

Comment: I doubt it's a version issue; more likely there is a header row like "date   value" that you should skip.

Comment: I copied unutbu's code directly and tested it. Error came from line " df.columns=['date', 'values']". I am using Python 2.7 with pandas 0.7.0

Comment: You should really try to update your pandas version. Current stable version is 0.12.0.